# chrome browser not getting launched after changing selenium version to 3.13.0

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium3

I was using 2.53 selenium version and now I have changed my selenium version to 3.13.0. 
With this version change chromedriver is not getting initialized. In simple words chrome is not getting launched. But if  I again change to selenium 2.53 then it works fine. I am using maven.

- Chrome browser version is 70
- Chrome driver version is 2.43

In pom.xml I changed below dependency version to 3.13.0:
- selenium-java
- selenium-server
- selenium-chrome-driver
- selenium-support

Any idea of this kind of issues. Let me know if you required more details

SeleniumWebdriver code:

```
public class SeleniumDriverSetup extends Thread {   


    public  static WebDriver getDriver(String strBrowser) throws Exception
    {
        WebDriver driver = null;
        ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(HelperMethods.getRunEngineFileName());
        String OS = GlobalConstants.operatingSystem;

        if(OS.equalsIgnoreCase("Windows")){     

            if(strBrowser.trim().toUpperCase().equals("CHROME"))
            {               
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",GlobalConstants.librariesPath +"chromedriver.exe"); 
                driver = new ChromeDriver();           
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                System.out.println("***CHROME DRIVER HAS BEEN CREATED");

            }           
        }   
    return driver;
    }
}
```

[click here to check pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8HWQ.png)

Comment: What is the Error you are getting?

Comment: nothing on console test case just does not execute and it mark it as failed

Comment: Console logs: ###The URL: https://www,google.com
###The BROWSER: CHROME
***key, toCheckLoginFunctionalityWithValidCredentials value
[TestNG] Running:
  D:\google_automationtests\testit.xml

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

===============================================
Regression_Automation_Test
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

Starting ChromeDriver 2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a) on port 10225
Only local connections are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that this import:

> selenium-chrome-driver

Should be not 3.13.0 but 2.42 or 2.43 (these two versions support Chrome version 70).

Comment: selenium-chrome-driver 3.13.0 is the package version and the 2.42 and 2.43 version you talking about are chromedriver versions